# Getting a value in a variable from a command output and using using that variable in next command in ansible

Tags: ansible

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "command_output.stdout_lines": [
        "Enter SYS, SYSTEM and PDB Admin user password: ",
        "Retype SYS, SYSTEM and PDB Admin user password: ",
        "{",
        "  \"jobId\" : \"17d14f12-4403-48f6-a0fe-00d645af86a9\",",
        "  \"status\" : \"Created\",",
        "  \"message\" : null,",
        "  \"reports\" : [ ],",
        "  \"createTimestamp\" : \"February 02, 2022 12:08:00 PM UTC\",",
        "  \"resourceList\" : [ ],",
        "  \"description\" : \"Database service creation with db name: AkashDB4\",",
        "  \"updatedTime\" : \"February 02, 2022 12:08:00 PM UTC\"",
        "}"
    ]
}
```

How do I get the value of jobId into a variable in ansible ?

Comment: Hi, WC to SO! What have you tried ?

Comment: I tried mdaniel's suggestion and it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`reject` filter](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#reject) will allow you to throw out the prompt lines, leaving only JSON in the remaining `list[str]`, which [`join`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#join) will then combine back into `str` and `from_json` will do as it says

```yaml
  - debug:
      msg: >-
        {{ (command_output.stdout_lines
        | reject("match", ".*user password:.*")
        | join("") | from_json).jobId
        }}
    vars:
      command_output:
        stdout_lines: [
          "Enter SYS, SYSTEM and PDB Admin user password: ",
          "Retype SYS, SYSTEM and PDB Admin user password: ",
          "{",
          "  \"jobId\" : \"17d14f12-4403-48f6-a0fe-00d645af86a9\",",
          "  \"status\" : \"Created\",",
          "  \"message\" : null,",
          "  \"reports\" : [ ],",
          "  \"createTimestamp\" : \"February 02, 2022 12:08:00 PM UTC\",",
          "  \"resourceList\" : [ ],",
          "  \"description\" : \"Database service creation with db name: AkashDB4\",",
          "  \"updatedTime\" : \"February 02, 2022 12:08:00 PM UTC\"",
          "}"
        ]
```

produces

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "17d14f12-4403-48f6-a0fe-00d645af86a9"
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @mdaniel !!